# TypeError : unhashable type

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

Not completely sure if it's scipy related that's why I include the python tag.

I have a grid of data. Whenever I try to access something in the grid like this :

```
d = pd.read_csv('Debugdata1.csv') 
d[1,:]
```

I get `TypeError: unhashable type`

Took a look at the data in a variable explorer : the `Index` of my data looks like this (1L,32,432 ... some more integers). Could this be the problem?

Here's the stack trace :

```
  File "<ipython-input-3-2f510ec7ef6f>", line 1, in <module>
    d[1,:]
  File "C:\Users\Hristo\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1797, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Users\Hristo\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1804, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Users\Hristo\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1082, in _get_item_cache
    res = cache.get(item)
```

Comment: On which line does the TypeError originate? Can you post the complete traceback?

Comment: @SethMMorton on the second one

Comment: You are using `pandas`, not a `scipy` module.  Print a sample of `d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `pandas` module, you access elements with `loc` or `iloc` or `ix`. In your case

```
d.iloc[1,:]
```

or

```
d.ix[1,:]
```

Comment: Thank you! After so much frustration at getting this error and trying to solve it I finally found your post :-)

Comment: @Alvis You are welcome. At first pandas was also frustrating for me. The more I learn and use it (for data analysis), the more amazing it feels. Start with [10 minutes to pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html), your time is good invested